# Using custom widgets on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, dll, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I created a GUI using Qt Creator for use in my RPi project, written in Python.  I found a custom LED widget DLL file that I added to Qt Creator, by copying it into QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer.  When I transfer my files to my RPi, it throws an exception.

```
  File "TempDisplayV2.py", line 114, in <module>
    window = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/__init__.py", line 226, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/Loader/loader.py", line 72, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix, basedir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 1000, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 807, in createUserInterface
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 262, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 785, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 253, in createWidget
    self.stack.push(self.setupObject(widget_class, parent, elem))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/uiparser.py", line 217, in setupObject
    obj = self.factory.createQObject(clsname, name, args, is_attribute)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/objcreator.py", line 106, in createQObject
    factory = self.findQObjectType(classname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/objcreator.py", line 131, in findQObjectType
    w = module.search(classname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/Loader/qobjectcreator.py", line 115, in search
    module = __import__(mname, {}, {}, (cls,))
ImportError: No module named 'qled'
```

I'm assuming the issue is because the DLL file doesn't exist on the Pi, although I thought that once you create the UI file, it should have all the code it needs to operate independently. So how do I make this work?

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running an RPi 3B+ with Buster and Python 3.6.

Comment: DLL files are for Windows not for Linux. Also it is most likely compiled for the x86 or AMD64 architecture, not for the ARM architecture of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: So can I compile my Python program into a exe or something that Linux would recognize?

Comment: @JamesFord In linux there is no .exe or .dll, what you have to do is install Qt in Rpi and compile the library